# Entity framework table names mapping at runtime

Tags: entity-framework, tablename

I need to import a huge amount of data without db work interruption. So there are two tables: Data and DataTemp(they are identical). At first data is uploaded to the temp table and then tables are swapped by backing up Data table and renaming DataTemp to Data(this example is simplified - there much more than two tables). Entity Framework is used in this project.

So the question is: is it possible to use entity framework to use DataTemp without duplicating the Data table in the schema? Is there a way to edit final sql before executing it to temporary replace table names? OnModelCreating doesn't fit because it's called once but I need to use both tables at different times.

Thanks!

Comment: What about multiple DbContexts that have the same models but different configurations as needed?

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: If second DbContext uses the same schema it means that it also uses the same mappings and saves data to same tables.

Comment: not if you use `DbModelBuilder` and possibly `EntityTypeConfiguration` instead of data annotations to define table mappings, which is the only thing different between his tables

Comment: Note, I haven't tried that solution myself, thus why its a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Datum
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Datum> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataTempContext : DataContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Datum>().ToTable("DataTemp");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is working for me.

Use of old:

```
        using (var context = new DataContext())
        {
            // illustrate original table name, Data
            Console.WriteLine(context.Data.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Add some real data, for LinqPad
            context.Data.Add(new Datum());
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

SQL output by WriteLine:

```
            SELECT
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
                FROM [Data] AS [Extent1]
```

Use of new:

```
        using (var context1 = new DataContext())
        using (var context2 = new DataTempContext())
        {
            // copy old table to new
            foreach (var d in context1.Data)
                context2.Data.Add(d);
            context2.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new DataTempContext())
        {
            // illustrate different table name, DataTemp
            Console.WriteLine(context.Data.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

SQL output by WriteLine:

```
            SELECT
                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
                FROM [DataTemp] AS [Extent1]
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried this. OnModelCreating is not called and data is saved to context1 tables.

Comment: weird ... are you sure `context2` was initialized to a `DataTempContext`?

I don't always attempt code I post using a compiler, but I did this time, and the problem _I_ had was that I wound up with Data.sdf and DataTemp.sdf SQL CE DB files, because the default connection string for DbContext does that: however, the generated SQL clearly showed `[DataTemp]` as the table name, so I was content that it worked.

Comment: @JohnCastleman to fix the default connectiong string error, you could call the base DbContext's constructor for the `DataTempContext` to set the connection string, ie: `public DataTempContext() : base("DataContext") { }`

Comment: Also, it might not like inheriting from `DataContext`. Not sure what EF is doing under the covers, but making an abstract class both contexts inherit from could make a difference

Comment: Figured out what was wrong in my case - the connection string. Removed meta and UnintentionalCodeFirstException's. It works now. Thank you!